# Is Agora RTM available for Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, agora.io

We would like to use Agora to develop a chat section in our Xamarin Forms App like [this](https://github.com/DreamTeamMobile/Agora-RTM-SDK-for-Xamarin). Chat will also support voice messages, calls and video calls. On Agora's when I look at SDKs available there are various options like Flutter, ReactJS, Windows, Android, iOS and so on but I can't find Xamarin Forms as platform. On the web I found some NUGET packages like [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Agora.Full.Forms/) for Xamarin Forms support, they look official but can't verify it. I found an example on github [here](https://github.com/DreamTeamMobile/Xamarin.Agora.Samples), but It is for video calls and not RTM.

Please help!

Comment: I search some info, but can not find any package about Agora RTM for Xamarin.Forms, but you can try to take a look [xamarin-forms-chat-sdk-demo](https://github.com/cometchat-go/xamarin-forms-chat-sdk-demo), it also enables you to add voice, video and text chat.

Comment: Thanks Cherry Bu. I also come to the same conclusion I have to opt for some other SDK like CometChat recommended by you.